# Conditionally stop JQuery tooltip open / close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I conditionally prevent tooltip open and close?
It seems like the "open" and "close" events can not be used to abort current open / close.

One workaround could be to set "disabled" option and handle open / close manually. But then it seems that the tooltip can not be opened manually without also enabling it. (And then it will close automatically) It also seems to have the side effect that the "title" attribute is removed, which is bad because there are other scripts that are using it.

I have also tried to disable events in the "create" event, like:
`$(this).tooltip().tooltip().off("mouseover mouseleave focusin focusout");`
It doesn't work, the tooltip still opens and closes automatically. (However, if I instead do that on "open" event it does prevent the tooltip from closing.)

Comment: `$(this).tooltip().off("mouseover mouseleave focusin focusout");` remove an extra `tooltip()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).tooltip("disable");
```